Parity of number of crossings of chord diagram
I would like to define the following sign for a given perfect matching $P$ of set of $2n$ elements:
$$\sigma_P=(-1)^k$$
where $k$ is the number of crossings in the chord diagram associated to $P$.
Is there a (well known) way to read off $k$ or $k\pmod 2$ directly from the matching $P$, without drawing the diagram itself?
E.g., given the 6-element matching $(13)(24)(56)$ can I tell that the number of crossings in its chord diagram is $k=1$ and hence that the sign is $\sigma=-1$?
